# Importing tables from multiple databases into Hadoop and Union

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I have this specific scenario:

There are year-wise databases in SQL Server with naming like "FOOXXYY" where XXYY denotes fiscal year. Now I want to take a specific table "bar" from all these Databases, Union it into a single table in hive and store it into the HDFS.

What will be the best and fastest approach to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create database, create partitioned table, add partitions, run 4 different sqoop commands to connect to each of the database and load data into partitions. Here are the sample code snippets.

Create database and then partition table like this;

```
CREATE TABLE `order_items`(
  `order_item_id` int, 
  `order_item_order_id` int, 
  `order_item_order_date` string, 
  `order_item_product_id` int, 
  `order_item_quantity` smallint, 
  `order_item_subtotal` float, 
  `order_item_product_price` float)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `order_month` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
```

You can then add partitions using these commands:

```
alter table order_items add partition (order_month=201301);
alter table order_items add partition (order_month=201302);
```

Once the table is created, you can run `describe formatted order_items`. It will give the path of the table and you can validate using dfs -ls command in hive.

```
From describe formatted
Location:               hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/retail_ods.db/order_items

dfs -ls /apps/hive/warehouse/retail_ods.db/order_items
```

You will get 2 directories, capture the path.

By now you have table and partitions for each of the year (for your case). Now you can use sqoop import command for each database to query from the table and copy into the respective partition.

You can find sample sqoop commands [here](https://github.com/dgadiraju/code/blob/master/hadoop/edw/hdp/sqoop/sqoop_demo.txt). You can even pass the query as part of sqoop import commands (Google sqoop user guide).

```
sqoop import \
  --connect "jdbc:mysql://sandbox.hortonworks.com:3306/retail_db" \
  --username=retail_dba \
  --password=hadoop \
  --table order_items \
  --target-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/retail_ods.db/order_items/order_month=201301 \
  --append \
  --fields-terminated-by '|' \
  --lines-terminated-by '\n' \
  --outdir java_files
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was helpful! :)